# Dell first boot failed, result in no session created

Tags: boot, dell, session, su

I just receive my brand new dell laptop wich is chiped with a pre-installed ubuntu-dell image.
So I did the first boot to create my account and an "unrecoverable error" (or similar) occured and it made a restart... and since then the laptop keep booting correctly to the light-dm manager (ubuntu 16.04) and the only session I can open is the guest session.... which basically can't make me manage anything to repair the system.

Shortly :
I have a ubuntu linux installed where no sudo password (or even a user session) has been created.

My question : How do I re-trigger the "first boot " wich allow me to create a proper session ? Or how do I solve this problem without installing a non-dell based ubuntu image (where the wifi controller doesn't work) ?

Thanks in advance !

Simon

Comment: Personally, I would be asking Dell for support. As much as people here would love to help, will messing around with it invalidate any support / warranty you have ?

Comment: Well, as how the official from my work explained it to me, Dell certify the hardware to work with their custom release of ubuntu but don't bring any support or warranty for this particular os ...
And of course, the dell based ubuntu image is not available in public ...

Comment: Is this a work provided machine or a personal machine? If the former, let work sort it out. If the latter, I would be tempted to download 16.04, create a bootbale USB and give that a try. After all, what do you have to lose? You'll find out if native Ubuntu works or not. It should.

Comment: Yes this is a work provided machine but I have the feelin that this will take a maximum amount of time  by letting the work  get a workaround :/ (these are new machines for them and they used to work with hp and centos before). But I bet I have no choice. I'll keep you in touch :)
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !
I must have used an old 16.04.2 usb installer  wich didn't provide the right linux kernel and thus did not support the network chipset (I assumed that it was a dell based driver available only on the chiped dell release) ..
The install worked with the latest 16.04.3 !

Thanks !

Simon